# Is there any way to increase the Azure Container App memory limit past 4GB?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I like the Azure container app service, but we are struggling with the 4GB limit per container.

Is there any way to increase this limit without switching to container instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dedicated workload profile:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/workload-profiles-overview

This should allow you to go up to 32 cores and 256 GB.

Comment: We just ran into this issue today as well - glad to see Microsoft is working on a solution! Thanks for the info.

Comment: I have set a dedicated workload however when I go to add more cpu/ram the portal still limits me to the consumption plan limits.  How do I set to 8cpu and 32 gb ram?

Comment: which profile did you set ?

Comment: Often i see most folks that build containers out there use .25 vCPU and 0.5GiB. does .5Gib actually mean .5GiB as we would normally think of it?  That seems ridiculously low.

Comment: depends what you are building bh .most app don't need much memory => really depend on what your app is doing  and how you scale it